# Вы знаете людей(,) рисовать умеющих?

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Вы знаете людей(,) рисовать умеющих?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна?

*Вы знАете людей, // **рисовАть умеющих?***

1. Интересное предложение! **Дистантное** расположение согласованного определения относительно определяемого слова? Такое определение **обязательно обособляется.**
2. А у Розенталя так: Не обособляются определения, **стоящие **ПОСЛЕ** существительного**, если последнее само по себе в данном предложении не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении.
3. **Вот и весь разговор!**  Даже слушать не пришлось. Грамматика!

**Где там мои оппоненты,** им слово!

**[Розенталь, пункт 7(3)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)**

Определение обособляется, если  3) **если оторвано в тексте от существительного:** Глаза смыкались и, полузакрытые, тоже улыбались (Т.); На лавке, разбросанные, лежали поршни, ружьё (Л. Т.); Настасья Петровна ещё раз обняла Егорушку, обозвала его ангельчиком и, заплаканная, стала собирать на стол (Ч.);

Comment: @Серж Почему НАРУШАЕТЕ ПРАВИЛО 7(3) о диктантном расположении определения. (Смотрите мой второй ответ.)

Comment: Определение при дистантном расположении действительно, обособляется. Но в примерах Розенталя определение не зависит от глагола. Обособлено причастие. В нашем примере определение зависит от инфинитива и тесно связано с ним.

Comment: Ср. : глаза смыкались полузакрытые. Запятая нужна?

Comment: Вы смеетесь? Вы видите согласованное определение УМЕЮЩИХ. Оно на расстоянии от сущ. ЛЮДЕЙ

Comment: Глаза смыкались полузакрытые. В данном случае тоже отдалено от существительного глаза. Запятая нужна?

Comment: В составе сказуемого.  Дуплексив, двойная связь.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна:

Вы знАете людей, // **рисовАть умеющих?**

Два ударения, две фонетические фразы.

Сравнить:

*Вы знаете / **рисовать умеющих** людЕй?*

Нет запятой, одно ударение.

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что возможен и вариант без запятой по пункту [2-2](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108):

*Вы знаете людей рисовать умеющих?*

Смысл в том, о каких именно людях спрашивают.

Пример из справочника:

*Если вы челов**е**к себя уваж**а**ющий… то непременно напроситесь на ругательства*.

Тоже два ударения. Я считаю, что случай подходит, тоже важная информация именно в обороте, тоже **причастный** оборот и тоже не обособлен.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150418/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Вы знаете людей(,) рисовать умеющих?***
>
> Нужна ли запятая?

**Возможны оба варианта — и с запятой, и без запятой**.

Но варианты эти будут иметь разную семантику.

> *Вы **знаете людей**, рисовать умеющих?*

= *Знаете ли вы тех людей, которые **умеют рисовать**?*

> *Вы **знаете** людей рисовать **умеющих**?*

= *Знаете ли вы тех (людей), которые **умеют рисовать людей**?*

Ср.: *Вы знаете **природу/лошадей/деревья** рисовать умеющих?*

Comment: Это больше похоже на правду, плюс от меня.

Comment: *Знаете ли вы тех (людей), которые **умеют рисовать, людей**?*

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр В вашем примере обособляем, поскольку это придаточное, а не оборот, стоящий перед существительным. Оборот бы не обособился, но придаточное обособить нужно.

Comment: Не кажется ли вам, что тот значение, которое вы вкладываете в структуру без запятой, не имеет никакого смысла?

Comment: @Серж: _ Не кажется ли вам, что то значение, которое вы вкладываете в структуру без запятой, не имеет никакого смысла?_  === Серж, я не совсем понял, к кому был обращён этот Ваш вопрос… Если ко мне — то отвечу так: **мне — не кажется!** А вот почему _бессмысленность_ в моей трактовке рассматриваемого предложения без запятой почудилась Вам — мне непонятно…

Comment: Слава, да поэтому, что пропущено местоимение тех.